# Find next time business is open; mysql hours calculation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I’m trying to figure out if a shop is currently within its opening hours, if not then select the next time its open.

Finally I need to be able to put the opening day as a specific date.

Can someone possible give me a tip how to construct this query?

Thanks in advance

```
CREATE TABLE `shop_hours` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `shop_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `day_of_week` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `open_time` time NOT NULL,
  `close_time` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `shop_hours` (`id`, `shop_id`, `day_of_week`, `open_time`, `close_time`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 0, '08:00:00', '24:00:00'),
    (2, 1, 1, '08:00:00', '24:00:00'),
    (3, 1, 2, '08:00:00', '24:00:00'),
    (4, 1, 3, '08:00:00', '24:00:00'),
    (5, 1, 4, '08:00:00', '24:00:00'),
    (6, 1, 5, '08:00:00', '24:00:00'),
    (7, 1, 6, '08:00:00', '24:00:00');
```

**Edit:**

To clarify a little I'm not looking to find open shops, but only open hours for ONE specific shop. Based on the opening/closing hour, and what time it is now. I will generate some selectable timestamps incremented by 15 minutes.

E.g. if a shop has just closed (1PM), I will need to use the next open day's open/closing time instead. (the shop isn't necessarily open every day, could be closed Sundays).

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what a cursor is used for - basically I just need to be fetch the next opening- and closing hours, also for a specific date.

Comment: how are records looked like? can you post also the results you desired?

Comment: What is the difference between `id` and `shop_id`?

Comment: id is just an incrementing value with no real use

Comment: @Kristian its use is that its the primary key. That's quite a real use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out shop_id's, that is open for `NOW()`

```
SELECT *
  FROM `shop_hours`
 WHERE `day_of_week` = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%w')
   AND CURTIME() BETWEEN `open_time` AND `close_time`
```

*Obsolete*:

To find *tomorrow*'s available `open_time`s:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `shop_hours`
 WHERE `day_of_week` = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%w')
```

**Edit** 2:

To find next available `open_time`s:

```
  SELECT `shop_id`,
         MIN(CAST(CONCAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ((7 + DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%w') - `day_of_week`) % 7) DAY)), ' ', `open_time`) AS DATETIME)) AS `next_open_datetime`
    FROM `shop_hours`
GROUP BY `shop_id`
```

**Edit**:

`DATE_FORMAT(*DATE*, '%w')` uses the format `0 = Sunday ... 6 = Saturday`

If you want to use the ISO format `1 = Monday ... 7 = Sunday` in your `day_of_week` field, you should bind php's `date('N')` to your query (or use Mysql's if function `IF(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%w') = 0, 7, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%w'))`, but that's ugly)

Comment: So to find the next open hours, I would first start out by using example 1, if results is empty, I would create a loop incrementing the interval day. Is this effective?

Comment: Keep in mind this won't work if you check at say ... 1AM in the morning and the shop is open on that day at 6AM; in other words it would only return those shops that are open when you run the script.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid i figured out too, edited to give always the next time it opens.

Comment: @pozs your edit 2 example seems very useful! However if I add the close_time in the select, it doesnt match the one of the open_date that is returned? Lastly is it possibly to split the date and open_time? Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: That select basically selects the minimum of all (next 7 days) opening datetimes - you should split to separate date & time in php. And, if you need the matching close_time, you should query against the returned datetime's day-of-week; you can't get them in one query.

Comment: @pozs - I need this expanded a little more, and you seem experienced. I'm afraid to ask, and not sure if breaking any rules, but is it possible to hire you?

Answer (score 2):

1) Check if shop is open. Result is empty, if shop is closed:

```
select * from shop_hours
where shop_id = $id
      and dayofweek(curdate()) = day_of_week
      and curtime() between open_time and close_time;
```

2) Find next open time:

```
(select open_time from shop_hours
 where shop_id = $id and curtime() < open_time
       and day_of_week >= dayofweek(curdate()))
union
(select open_time from shop_hours
 where shop_id = $id and curtime() < open_time
 order by day_of_week)
 union
(select open_time from shop_hours
 where shop_id = $id and curtime() > close_time
       and day_of_week >= dayofweek(curdate()))
union
(select open_time from shop_hours
 where shop_id = $id and curtime() > close_time
 order by day_of_week)
limit 1;
```

Untested, but this *should* respect weekend wraparound and holes in the week (i.e. closed days).

Keep in mind, that [dayofweek()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) numbers 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, ... If your table stores the weekdays in a different format, you must adjust the query accordingly.