# holidays in mysql for multiple stores

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in a MySQL database with shops and days. I need to check if the shop is open on that day.

Before checking if a shop is open following this method:
[Find next time business is open; mysql hours calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100717/find-next-time-business-is-open-mysql-hours-calculation) I need to check whether the shop is on some holiday before checking if it's open or not.

Is it good to have a table with :

Shop ID  |  Days

xxx        |        number,number,number, etc..

that the application (written in PHP) queries checking whether the [yday] is contained in the Days string (a comma separated values string)?
The Shop ID will be a foreign key in the Shops table, and the application will always know in advance which shops to run this query for, not the other way around.

I have found no computationally cheap or elegant solution around so far. It may be a very simple question, but the solutions are soo many I'm having a  hard time figuring out the different performance issues.

## Edit 1

Considering also the performance implications of the query as follows, having considered @GordonLinoff answer as the best solution:

```
$ShopId = //a POST or GET 
$day = //a POST or GET

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT day FROM table WHERE ShopId = '$ShopId' AND day = $day");

if(mysql_num_rows($query)== 0){
   echo "Shop open";
}
else{
 echo "Shop closed";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have a single table with a row for each shop and each holiday.  So a row would be:

```
ShopId Day
xxx    number
xxx    number
xxx    number
```

You can then easily check inclusion in this table using SQL.  And, it will be quite efficient if you have an index on `(ShopId, Day)`.

Comment: Apologies if I take advantage of your knowledge. When will creating tables per each shop represent a problem (let's say thousands of shops)? Also, why would I build the index on both columns rather than only on the day, after all, the shop ID will be exactly the same on the whole table.

Comment: You will be creating one table, not one table per shop.

Comment: You don't create tables for each shop.  You create one table.  If you don't know about database normalization, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: @TimDearborn . . . I didn't realize the original phrasing was ambiguous.  One table is what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've updated my question. I misunderstood your answer and I was surprised. One table makes sense. Is the performance the best considering the query in the question? We can then close this thread as solved.

Comment: @user3132821 . . . Yes, assuming you have the appropriate index, the performance will be quite optimal.